# Ruby on Rails error when creating record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following the Kevin Skoglund tutorial for Ruby on Rails called [Ruby on Rails 4 Essential Training](http://www.lynda.com/Ruby-Rails-tutorials/Ruby-Rails-4-Essential-Training/139989-2.html). In the section 'Create Record' I am having the following error after simply trying to create a record:

```
George$ pwd
/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms
George$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0> subject = Subject.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Subject
from (irb):1
from /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/George/Sites/simple_cms/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/George/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

As I am still in the early stages of learning I cannot establish what the cause might be although it appears to be gem related based on the errors return.

If anyone has any suggestion and maybe a tip on how I can work out what the error and fix is for myself it would be appreciated as I really want to keep learning.

Comment: do you have a model or class called `Subject`?

Comment: Have you run the `rails generate model Subject` command referenced in the 'Generating a model' section of the tutorial? That should have created you a file called `subject.rb` in the `app/models` directory containing a class called `Subject`. The error you are getting is saying that the `Subject` class could not be found (it is nothing to do with gems).

Answer (score 0):

```
George$ pwd
/Users/George/Sites/simple_cms
George$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)

> rails generate model Subject name:string type:string 

> rake db:migrate

> rails console 

> sub = Subject.new
```

Try this.